# bash if -a vs -e option

Tags: bash

Both about `-a` and `-e` options in [Bash documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions) is said:

```
-a file
    True if file exists.
-e file
    True if file exists.
```

Trying to get what the difference is I ran the following script:

```
resin_dir=/Test/Resin_wheleph/Results

if [ -e ${resin_dir} ] ; then
    echo "-e ";
fi

if [ ! -e ${resin_dir} ] ; then
    echo "! -e";
fi

if [ -a ${resin_dir} ] ; then
    echo "-a";
fi

if [ ! -a ${resin_dir} ] ; then
    echo "! -a";
fi
```

`/Test/Resin_wheleph/Results` exists and is a directory. And this is what I get:

```
-e
-a
! -a
```

which seems to be a little strange (notice `-a` and  `! -a`). But when I use double brackets (e. g. `if [[ -e ${resin_dir} ]]`) in the similar script it gives reasonable output:

```
-e
-a
```

So:

1. What is a difference between `-a` and `-e` options?
2. Why `-a` produces a strange result when used inside single brackets?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

I researched, and this is quite hairy:

`-a` is deprecated, thus isn't listed in the manpage for `/usr/bin/test` anymore, but still in the one for bash. Use `-e` . For single '[', the bash builtin behaves the same as the `test` bash builtin, which behaves the same as `/usr/bin/[` and `/usr/bin/test` (the one is a symlink to the other). Note the effect of `-a` depends on its position: If it's at the start, it means `file exists`. If it's in the middle of two expressions, it means logical `and`.

`[ ! -a /path ] && echo exists` doesn't work, as the bash manual points out that `-a` is considered a binary operator there, and so the above isn't parsed as a `negate -a ..` but as a `if '!' and '/path' is true` (non-empty). Thus, your script always outputs `"-a"` (which actually tests for files), and `"! -a"` which actually is a binary `and` here.

For `[[`, `-a` isn't used as a binary `and` anymore (`&&` is used there), so its unique purpose is to check for a file there (although being deprecated). So, negation actually does what you expect.

Comment: The bash builtin uses -a as -e in unary mode and -a as AND in binary mode. Using [[ ]]  invokes the bashs builtin, thats why you got reasonable output with it. The single [ bracket invokes as mentioned  the test binary which accepts the unary but does not treat it right (should be used as binary)

Comment: Very few shells actually invoke /bin/test (or /bin/[) when you write 'if [ ... ]'.  Once upon a long time ago - yes; nowadays, no.  Not even vanilla Bourne shell.

Comment: yeah i think shell builtins always take precedence

Comment: '[' isn't a builtin at all for bash. see my note on my answer

Comment: wrong: [js@HOST2 cpp]$ help [
[: [ arg... ]
    This is a synonym for the "test" builtin, but the last
    argument must be a literal `]', to match the opening `['.

Comment: On my system /usr/bin/test and /usr/bin/[ are completely different programs:
[wheleph ~]$ ls -l /usr/bin/test /usr/bin/\\[
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 31384 Apr 10  2006 /usr/bin/[
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 28728 Apr 10  2006 /usr/bin/test

Comment: wheleph. i don't know why that is :) here they are just symlinks at least

Comment: I'm not really grokking this answer well this morning. Once I understand what it is trying to explain, we may want to edit the answer and mark the code explicitely as, this specified line is the answer.

Answer (score 7):

The '`-a`' option to the test operator has one meaning as a unary operator and another as a binary operator.  As a binary operator, it is the 'and' connective (and '`-o`' is the 'or' connective).  As a unary operator, it apparently tests for a file's existence.

The `autoconf` system advises you to avoid using '`-a`' because it causes confusion; now I see why.  Indeed, in portable shell programming, it is best to combine the conditions with '`&&`' or '`||`'.

I think @litb is on the right track.  When you have '`! -a ${resin_dir}`', Bash may be interpreting it as "is the string '!' non-empty and is the string in '${resin_dir}' non-empty, to which the answer is yes.  The Korn shell has a different view on this, and the Bourne shell yet another view - so stay away from '`-a`'.

On Solaris 10:

```
$ bash -c 'x=""; if [ ! -a "$x" ] ; then echo OK ; else echo Bad; fi'
Bad
$ ksh -c 'x=""; if [ ! -a "$x" ] ; then echo OK ; else echo Bad; fi'
OK
$ sh -c 'x=""; if [ ! -a "$x" ] ; then echo OK ; else echo Bad; fi'
sh: test: argument expected
$
```

Answer (score 0):

The double bracket [[ exp ]] is a bash builtin. In bash -a and -e are the same, probably for some backwards compatibility.

The single bracket [ exp ] is an alias for the external command "test". In "test", -a is a logical AND. Although [ nothing AND $STRING ] looks like it should be false, test has some syntax quirks, which is why I recommend using the bash builtin [[ exp ]], which tends to be more sane.

Note:
bash really does call /bin/[ when you use "[".

```
$ [ $UNASIGNED_VAR == "bar" ]
bash: [: ==: unary operator expected
```

the error shows bash called [. An strace also shows "execve("/usr/bin/[", ..."

Comment: [js@HOST2 cpp]$ alias foo
bash: alias: foo: not found
[js@HOST2 cpp]$ 
does that mean alias now is a extern command? no, it's still a builtin :)

Comment: darn, good one :). Still, strace'ing a bash script reveals "execve("/usr/bin/[",
...

Comment: Interesting: on Solaris, using 'truss -o bash.truss bash ...' as in my answer and then using 'grep -n exec bash.truss' shows only line 1 executing bash itself.  So that is rather odd.  (There also isn't a /usr/bin/[ on Solaris - there is a /usr/bin/test.)