# Why does negated file existence check in bash return weird results in case of existing target?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, if-statement

I wish to perform an action if a file does not exists in bash with the following command:

```
if [ ! -a $HOME/.some_directory ] ; then 
     # do something
fi
```

However the `#do something` part is always executed regardless of the existence of `$HOME/.some_directory`.

I've created a small test where I have tried all cases:

- nonexistent directory check
- negated nonexistent directory check
- existent directory check
- negated existent directory check ( this is the only one returning an "invalid" result) - or I am doing something wrong

Here is a screenshot of the result:

[image]

Notes:

- `~/bin` is present while `~/bina` is not
- I am using bash version: `4.3.18`
- I've used `$HOME` instead of `~` because of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8409024/desktop-test-txt-no-such-file-or-directory)
- I've taken the file existence check suggestions from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638975/how-do-i-tell-if-a-file-does-not-exist-in-bash) and [this reference](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is [specified in POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html):

> 3 arguments:
>
> - If $2 is a binary primary, perform the binary test of $1 and $3.

In your case, `$2` is a `-a` which is a binary primary operator, so `$1` and `$3` are treated as binary tests. Single words are tested as if with `-n` ("is non-empty string").

This means that your test is equivalent to:

```
[[ -n "!" && -n "$HOME/.some_directory" ]]
```

Answer (score 3):

`-a` as a test if a file exists, is a unary expression ( one-sided ) is a remnant of `ksh86` (KornShell 86). It has become obsolete in more modern, derivative shells and has been replaced by `-e` which is part of the POSIX standard, but in many shells it is still a synonym of `-e` for backwards compatibility.

`-a` can also be used a binary expression (two sided) and then it means an AND logical operator (which is also obsolescent). Here `-a` is interpreted this way because there is a `!` symbol in front of it and a string behind it. Both sides evaluate to true, so by using AND the outcome then becomes logically true.

Using `-e` fixes this since it cannot be interpreted in another way.

Another way would have been to negate that outcome of the test command like so:

```
if ! [ -a $HOME/.some_directory ] ; then
```

or use parentheses for grouping:

```
if [ ! \( -a $HOME/.some_directory \) ] ; then
```

But at any rate it is better to stick with operands that are not deprecated / obsolescent..

Answer (score 2):

What happens if you try `-d` instead of `-a`?

> [ -d FILE ]   True if FILE exists and is a directory.
>
> ~ http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html

---

Also, seems like `-a` is deprecated - please review [this StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321348/bash-if-a-vs-e-option) for details.

Comment: awesome. thanks for the reference (+1). I wish I've found it earlier

Answer (score 1):

You put a wrong operator; "-a" means AND.

You need "-e" to check if a file exists.

Comment: You are right, with `-e` works the right way. But then why does [this guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html) begin with this example: `[ -a FILE ] True if FILE exists.` ? Are they wrong? (PS. I can see they also list `-e` with the same explanation)

Comment: He described in the very beginning; he performed an action to check if a file doesn't exist and then...

Comment: You pointed me in the right direction (`-e`) (+1 for that) but the actual answer to '*why*' was given by `that other guy`. Thank you